# How to change the btn style using javascript in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a written javascript function that will change the button class type from btn btn-success to btn btn-danger on click. How can I do so? Basically, I want to toggle the btn class everytime.

```
<td>   
                    <div id="btn_modal_Edit" class="btn btn-success"   runat="server">
                    <a href='CreateAccount.aspx?Id=<%# Eval("ID")%>&RoleName=<%# Eval("RoleName")%>'>Edit</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="btn_modal_Status" class="btn btn-success" runat="server">
                    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="fun(<%# Eval("ID")%>)">Status</a>
                    </div>
                </td>

function fun(id)
{
    document.getElementById('<%= hfId.ClientID%>').value = id;
    document.getElementById('btn_modal_Edit').className = "btn-danger";
    document.getElementById('btn_modal_status').className = "btn-danger";
}
```

This function fails because it cannot find  document.getElementById('btn_modal_Edit') and document.getElementById('btn_modal_status').

Any ideas to fix this?

Comment: Did you check those elements are with those IDs? You have them as `runat="server"` for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Every thing is working fine with this:

```
document.getElementById("btn_modal_Edit").className = "btn-danger";
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/syzuud2b/)

Comment: not working for me - All these td tags are asp.net datasource listview

Comment: Bro, check  the fidlle. It is selecting element and given style is applied on  the element